# CMake error: For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path

Tags: cmake, mingw

I am trying to built a "Hello World" project with Qt 5 and cmake under MinGW.
This is the CMakeLists.txt file (taken from the on-line doc):

```
project(Qt5_cmake_test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/mingw48_32")

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the QtWidgets library
find_package(Qt5Widgets)

# Add the source files from the current directory
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# Tell CMake to create the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${SRC_LIST})

# Use the Widgets module from Qt5
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} Qt5::Widgets)
```

The source code is the one generated automatically when creating a new project (which produces an empty window).

Configuring from the Windows command prompt with: `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..\Qt5_cmake_test`

I get these errors:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeMinGWFindMake.cmake:20 (message):
  sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe

  For MinGW make to work correctly sh.exe must NOT be in your path.

  Run cmake from a shell that does not have sh.exe in your PATH.

  If you want to use a UNIX shell, then use MSYS Makefiles.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (project)


CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/pietro.mele/projects/tests/buildSystem_test/Qt5_cmake_test-build/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCCompiler.cmake

CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/pietro.mele/projects/tests/buildSystem_test/Qt5_cmake_test-build/CMakeFiles/2.8.11.2/CMakeCXXCompiler.cma
ke
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

So it seems it is not able to find the compiler. Is there a way to let cmake find it on its own, or just giving it the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH directory?
Do I have to manually specify all those variables in the makefile or as environment variables in Windows?

I tried both from the standard Windows command prompt and from the one provided by Qt, with the same result. Is it OK to build from the Windows command prompt, or should I do it from the MinGW's shell?

Platform:
Qt 5.1
CMake 2.8.11.2
MinGW/GCC 4.8
Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This CMakeLists.txt file works properly:

```
project(Qt5_cmake_test)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:/Qt/Qt5.1.1/5.1.1/mingw48_32")

# Find includes in corresponding build directories
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
# Instruct CMake to run moc automatically when needed.
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

# Find the Qt libraries
find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)

# Add the source files from the current directory
aux_source_directory(. SRC_LIST)

# Tell CMake to create the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} WIN32 ${SRC_LIST})

# Use Qt5 modules
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    Qt5::Widgets
    Qt5::WinMain)
```

The changes are:

Added `find_package(Qt5Core REQUIRED)`.
Added `Qt5::WinMain` to `target_link_libraries`.

Answer (score 2):

Get the git path out of your `PATH` before running `cmake`.

Here is the magic to do that:

```
set PATH=%PATH:C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin;=%
```

Answer (score 0):

In some of my answer here on SO, I have described. CMake does not like sh.exe.

```
sh.exe was found in your PATH, here:

  C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe
```

Solution : Rename `C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/sh.exe`  shortly.

For example:

```
C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin/shxx.exe
```

But do not forget when everything is built. rename properly again.

Comment: Well, considering I would have to rename it for every run of CMake followed by a run of git, ad vice-versa, ... I am sure it will become annoying. Either I will ignore the warning or I will write a script that does it automatically when I call git.

Comment: @Pietro : Annoys me that a lot. In my environment, it is `c:\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe` . Have not figured out by now why bother sh.exe CMake.

Comment: You can also remove C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/bin from the PATH environment variable.

Comment: That's crazy! Don't just rename things like that.